# JQuery and changing img src

Tags: jquery

Hi I was following a tutorial and one aspect doesn't seem to work and I don't understand where I am going wrong.

When I hover over a thumbnail, it should change the main image to what I just hovered over. I think I just missed something in the JQuery section of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<title>Build A Greyscale Image Gallery</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<script>

    $.(document).ready(function(){
        $.('.thumb').hover(function(){
            $('.main_image img').attr('src',$(this).children('img').attr('src'));
            });
    })

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Build A Greyscale Image Gallery</h2>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="main_image">
        <img src="images/aston.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="selection_image">
            <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <img src="images/aston9.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to remove `.` after `$`. Try something like below!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumb').hover(function(){
        $('.main_image img').attr('src',$(this).children('img').attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Also suggest to add `jQuery` if not added.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```